# Converting XML file to Nib file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml

I want to know about conversion  from XML file to Nib file in objective-c,My requirement is commonly Xib file after compilation it will converted into NIB file (binary Data Format) now i want to give an external Xml file to My Project and I want to convert this file as a Nib file. Is this possible?Give me suggestions(it means that replacement of Xib file With XML file).

Comment: XIBs are an extended, and highly complicated, version of a plist.  In order to get an acceptable "starting point" for what you need, you should probably create an empty nib, and open it in textedit or open it raw in Xcode to see what it's actually writing.

Comment: Is this Possible by using XML?

Comment: Not the XML you've seen.  XIBs are almost like object graphs, which means they look and act more like plists, but yes, if you have the right top-level tags, you can successfully just rename an XML file to a XIB.  Compiling it is another story.

Answer (score 0):

Here I listed the details of plain iPad xib configuration, It is in the form of plist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB" version="8.00">
    <data>
        <int key="IBDocument.SystemTarget">1536</int>
        <string key="IBDocument.SystemVersion">12A206j</string>
        <string key="IBDocument.InterfaceBuilderVersion">2519</string>
        <string key="IBDocument.AppKitVersion">1172.1</string>
        <string key="IBDocument.HIToolboxVersion">613.00</string>
        <object class="NSMutableDictionary" key="IBDocument.PluginVersions">
            <string key="NS.key.0">com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin</string>
            <string key="NS.object.0">1856</string>
        </object>
        <array key="IBDocument.IntegratedClassDependencies">
            <string>IBProxyObject</string>
            <string>IBUIView</string>
        </array>
        <array key="IBDocument.PluginDependencies">
            <string>com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin</string>
        </array>
        <object class="NSMutableDictionary" key="IBDocument.Metadata">
            <string key="NS.key.0">PluginDependencyRecalculationVersion</string>
            <integer value="1" key="NS.object.0"/>
        </object>
        <array class="NSMutableArray" key="IBDocument.RootObjects" id="1000">
            <object class="IBProxyObject" id="841351856">
                <string key="IBProxiedObjectIdentifier">IBFilesOwner</string>
                <string key="targetRuntimeIdentifier">IBIPadFramework</string>
            </object>
            <object class="IBProxyObject" id="606714003">
                <string key="IBProxiedObjectIdentifier">IBFirstResponder</string>
                <string key="targetRuntimeIdentifier">IBIPadFramework</string>
            </object>
            <object class="IBUIView" id="766721923">
                <reference key="NSNextResponder"/>
                <int key="NSvFlags">274</int>
                <string key="NSFrame">{{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}</string>
                <reference key="NSSuperview"/>
                <reference key="NSWindow"/>
                <object class="NSColor" key="IBUIBackgroundColor">
                    <int key="NSColorSpace">3</int>
                    <bytes key="NSWhite">MQA</bytes>
                    <object class="NSColorSpace" key="NSCustomColorSpace">
                        <int key="NSID">2</int>
                    </object>
                </object>
                <object class="IBUISimulatedStatusBarMetrics" key="IBUISimulatedStatusBarMetrics">
                    <int key="IBUIStatusBarStyle">2</int>
                </object>
                <string key="targetRuntimeIdentifier">IBIPadFramework</string>
            </object>
        </array>
        <object class="IBObjectContainer" key="IBDocument.Objects">
            <array class="NSMutableArray" key="connectionRecords">
                <object class="IBConnectionRecord">
                    <object class="IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection" key="connection">
                        <string key="label">view</string>
                        <reference key="source" ref="841351856"/>
                        <reference key="destination" ref="766721923"/>
                    </object>
                    <int key="connectionID">3</int>
                </object>
            </array>
            <object class="IBMutableOrderedSet" key="objectRecords">
                <array key="orderedObjects">
                    <object class="IBObjectRecord">
                        <int key="objectID">0</int>
                        <array key="object" id="0"/>
                        <reference key="children" ref="1000"/>
                        <nil key="parent"/>
                    </object>
                    <object class="IBObjectRecord">
                        <int key="objectID">-1</int>
                        <reference key="object" ref="841351856"/>
                        <reference key="parent" ref="0"/>
                        <string key="objectName">File's Owner</string>
                    </object>
                    <object class="IBObjectRecord">
                        <int key="objectID">-2</int>
                        <reference key="object" ref="606714003"/>
                        <reference key="parent" ref="0"/>
                    </object>
                    <object class="IBObjectRecord">
                        <int key="objectID">2</int>
                        <reference key="object" ref="766721923"/>
                        <reference key="parent" ref="0"/>
                    </object>
                </array>
            </object>
            <dictionary class="NSMutableDictionary" key="flattenedProperties">
                <string key="-1.CustomClassName">ViewController</string>
                <string key="-1.IBPluginDependency">com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin</string>
                <string key="-2.CustomClassName">UIResponder</string>
                <string key="-2.IBPluginDependency">com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin</string>
                <string key="2.IBPluginDependency">com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin</string>
            </dictionary>
            <dictionary class="NSMutableDictionary" key="unlocalizedProperties"/>
            <nil key="activeLocalization"/>
            <dictionary class="NSMutableDictionary" key="localizations"/>
            <nil key="sourceID"/>
            <int key="maxID">3</int>
        </object>
        <object class="IBClassDescriber" key="IBDocument.Classes">
            <array class="NSMutableArray" key="referencedPartialClassDescriptions">
                <object class="IBPartialClassDescription">
                    <string key="className">ViewController</string>
                    <string key="superclassName">UIViewController</string>
                    <object class="IBClassDescriptionSource" key="sourceIdentifier">
                        <string key="majorKey">IBProjectSource</string>
                        <string key="minorKey">./Classes/ViewController.h</string>
                    </object>
                </object>
            </array>
        </object>
        <int key="IBDocument.localizationMode">0</int>
        <string key="IBDocument.TargetRuntimeIdentifier">IBIPadFramework</string>
        <bool key="IBDocument.PluginDeclaredDependenciesTrackSystemTargetVersion">YES</bool>
        <int key="IBDocument.defaultPropertyAccessControl">3</int>
        <bool key="IBDocument.UseAutolayout">YES</bool>
        <string key="IBCocoaTouchPluginVersion">1856</string>
    </data>
</archive>
```

But there is no document found about the elements in plist.

One Solution I found is check by creating a similar XIB file and use its plist.
And try this, write this plist data with extension as .xib and load that file.

May this link help u,

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618313/load-and-display-a-xib-from-the-web)

thanks,

Naveen Shan